# Data replication between SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server 2008 R2 is valid?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

We have two servers with two SQL Server instance. we have plan to make first one SQL Server 2016 for production database and the second one SQL Sever 2008 R2 for the same database as reporting side.

Can we create a replication solution between SQL Server 2016 & 2008 R2? If not: is there another solution to migrate updated data between these two instances?

Comment: First of all is it safe to use `SQL Server 2016` in production ?

Comment: do you mean SQL Server 2016 not stable or under test?

Comment: Merge replication seems to be supported but not transactional replication. [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid Replication between 2016 and 2008 is deprecated per Microsoft.
[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143550.aspx)

> Replication is supported if each SQL Server endpoint is within two
>   major versions of the current version of SQL Server. Consequently, SQL
>   Server 2016 does not support replication to or from SQL Server 2008 or
>   SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use 2 different versions though.  If you use 2016 in both environments there will be no trouble.  And 2016 is still bleeding edge and hasn't been used widely in Production environments which is why there is still hesitancy in using it.  I saw a statistic that said .5% of active users use 2016 in Production at this time.  2008R2 is currently at the top at 38%.